# Issue setting symbolic link for Julia Lang

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, symbolic-link, julia-lang

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I guess my question is a general question about symbolic links with a specific set up. However, I am new to Ubuntu and maybe I am wrong and my issue lies somewhere else.

I want to set up a way of just typing `julia` or something similar in the command line and getting Julia 1.3.1 (from Installation 2) running.

I  have recently installed Julia programming language in two different ways:

- [Installation 1] Using `sudo apt install julia`
- [Installation 2] Using the official generic binaries

I have followed the instructions in this link: https://julialang.org/downloads/platform.html

So far, when I run `julia` in the command line, I get Installation 1 going (which is version 1.0.4 of Julia Lang). However, I would like the command `julia` (or `julia131`, the syntax is not the main point here for me) to start Installation 2, which is Julia 1.3.1. I have explored some of the suggestions available in the link above.

- So far, I have only managed to run Julia 1.3.1 using `/home/<me>/julia-1.3.1/bin/julia`
- I have tried creating a symbolic link using the following command `sudo ln -s home/<me>/julia-1.3.1/bin/julia /usr/bin/julia` (I have also tried `sudo ln -s home/<me>/julia-1.3.1/bin/julia /usr/bin/julia131`). I have inspected my `/usr/bin/`directory and I can actually see the archives `julia` and `julia131` there. However, when I try to run them, from `/usr/bin`, neither of them work.
- I have tried adding `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/home/<me>/julia-1.3.1/bin"` and `export PATH="$PATH:/home/<me>/julia-1.3.1/bin"` (I was not sure which syntax was the correct one) as suggested in the link. It also did not work, but I am not fully confident that I am doing it right.
- I have added `PATH=$PATH:/home/roberto/julia-1.3.1/bin/` to `.profile`. Not sure how this would work, but I have read it somewhere in the internet. In any case, it did not work for me.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you want `julia-1.3.1` to be found *first*, its location needs to go ahead of other locations in your path i.e. `PATH="/home/<me>/julia-1.3.1/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver! That has worked! Should I worry that this line in my `./bashrc` will create any problems for other applications or commands? Also, once I have a line like this in my `./bashrc` can I add another one for another program I have?